# Is there a way to implement methods like __len__ or __eq__ as classmethods?

Tags: python, class

It is pretty easy to implement `__len__(self)` method in Python so that it handles `len(inst)` calls like this one:

```
class A(object):

  def __len__(self):
    return 7

a = A()
len(a) # gives us 7
```

And there are plenty of alike methods you can define (`__eq__`, `__str__`, `__repr__` etc.).
I know that Python classes are objects as well.

My question: can I somehow define, for example, `__len__` so that the following works:

```
len(A) # makes sense and gives some predictable result
```

Comment: "Can I?" or "Should I?"

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate some on your intended use-case, because I'm failing to imagine any situation where this could be useful. It might help us give you an idea of how to solve this better (if there is a better way), or at least help us help you accomplish your goal better.

Comment: @ChrisLutz What if the class kept track of how many instances were instantiated of it, or had a list of all its instances?

Comment: I'd argue using a static field/property/member that is of an enumerable type, used like `len(TheClass.instances)`, is far more readable and intuitive to the next developer than `len(TheClass)`. I'd intuitively expect that `len(TheClass)` either gives an error or counts the number of fields/properties/members of the class itself, behaving something like `len(TheClass.__dict__.keys())`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a "metaclass"... just like `a` is an instance of class `A`, `A` is an instance of class as well, referred to as a metaclass. By default, Python  classes are instances of the `type` class (the only exception is under Python 2, which has some legacy "old style" classes, which are those which don't inherit from `object`). You can check this by doing `type(A)`... it should return `type` itself (yes, that object has been overloaded a little bit).

Metaclasses are powerful and brain-twisting enough to deserve more than the quick explanation I was about to write... a good starting point would be this stackoverflow question: [What is a Metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python).

For your particular question, for Python 3, the following creates a metaclass which aliases `len(A)` to invoke a class method on A:

```
class LengthMetaclass(type):

    def __len__(self):
        return self.clslength()

class A(object, metaclass=LengthMetaclass):

    @classmethod
    def clslength(cls):
        return 7

print(len(A))
```

*(Note: Example above is for Python 3.  The syntax is slightly different for Python 2: you would use `class A(object):\n    __metaclass__=LengthMetaclass` instead of passing it as a parameter.)*

The reason `LengthMetaclass.__len__` doesn't affect *instances* of `A` is that attribute resolution in Python first checks the instance dict, then walks the class hierarchy `[A, object]`, but it never consults the metaclasses. Whereas accessing `A.__len__` first consults the instance `A`, then walks *it's* class hierarchy, which consists of `[LengthMetaclass, type]`.

Comment: Note that in Python 3 a metaclass would be defined like `class A(object, metaclass=LengthMetaclass):`

Comment: This is not normally what you want, because it does not use the object's instance variables, but returns the same value for all instances.

Normally you would just want to implement __len__ in your class. See [this article](https://realpython.com/operator-function-overloading/#giving-a-length-to-your-objects-using-len).

Answer (score 5):

Since a class is an instance of a metaclass, one way is to use a custom metaclass:

```
>>> Meta = type('Meta', (type,), {'__repr__': lambda cls: 'class A'})
>>> A = Meta('A', (object,), {'__repr__': lambda self: 'instance of class A'})
>>> A
class A
>>> A()
instance of class A
```

Answer (score 1):

I fail to see how the Syntax specifically is important, but if you really want a simple way to implement it, just is the normal **len**(self) that returns len(inst) but in your implementation make it return a class variable that all instances share:

```
class A:
    my_length = 5
    def __len__(self):
        return self.my_length
```

and you can later call it like that:

```
len(A()) #returns 5
```

obviously this creates a temporary instance of your class, but length only makes sense for an instance of a class and not really for the concept of a class (a Type object).

Editing the metaclass sounds like a very bad idea and unless you are doing something for school or to just mess around I really suggest you rethink this idea..

Answer (score -6):

try this:

```
class Lengthy:
    x = 5
    @classmethod
    def __len__(cls):
        return cls.x
```

The @classmethod allows you to call it directly on the class, but your len implementation won't be able to depend on any instance variables:

```
a = Lengthy()
len(a)
```

Comment: Wow this is so simple compare to the meta class explanation by Eli Collins. Any catch?

Comment: This look like the value is going to be the same for all Lengthy instances?

Comment: @huggie The catch is that it doesn't work. `len(Lengthy)` will throw an exception. This answer should be deleted.

Comment: `len(a)` seems to return `5` in Python 3.7.3.

Comment: @user1338062 `len` will works on the instance (`len(Lengthy())`), but not on the class (`len(Lengthy)`). It raise a `TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()`.