# Object Oriented Black Jack with Python - Deck has no length?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a blackjack game in Python.  However, when I try to shuffle and deal a card from my deck object, I get an error that states that my 'deck' object has no length.  Can anybody help resolve this?  Thanks

```
def deal():
    deck = Deck()
    player = Hand()
    dealer = Hand()
    random.shuffle(deck)
    player.add_card(deck.deal_card())
    player.add_card(deck.deal_card())
    dealer.add_card(deck.deal_card())
    dealer.add_card(deck.deal_card())
    prompt()
```

Comment: How are you getting the error? Are you trying to call something like `len(deck)`?

Comment: Can you share the code that is producing the error? Also, you have a `Deck` class, but you don't show an object called `deck`.

Comment: If I do `x = Deck()` then `len(x.deck)` I get `52`.

Comment: Here is the full code

Comment: It could be really helpful for others if you reduce your problem to a minimal example (maybe 20 lines or so) showing only stuff relevant to *reproduce* your issue. I know that it is some work to get such an minimal example, but it greatly increases the value of your question and makes the answers more valueable to community. :)

Comment: @user3002315 What made you think you needed to post all of your code? The code snippet was fine - you need to *explain the problem.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to use the `len` function on a `Deck` object itself as opposed to using it on the instance variable `deck` of a `Deck` object. If `d` is an instance of class `Deck`, you should call `len(d.deck)`, or even better, implement a getter method for `self.deck` and use something like `len(d.get_deck())`.

post-op-edit-edit:

You are trying to call `shuffle` on the `Deck` object itself as opposed to the `list` `deck` which is stored in your `Deck` object. Part of the confusion probably comes from the fact that you decided to name the class `Deck` and its instance variable `deck`. If you want the `list` `deck`, you need to issue `deck = Deck().deck` in your `deal` function.

edit in response to comment:

Of course, you cannot call `deal_card` on the `list` `deck`. You can do

```
def deal():
    deckObject = Deck()
    deckList = deckObject.deck 
    player = Hand()
    dealer = Hand()
    random.shuffle(deckList)
    player.add_card(deckObject.deal_card())
    player.add_card(deckObject.deal_card())
    dealer.add_card(deckObject.deal_card())
    dealer.add_card(deckObject.deal_card())
    prompt()
```

The notation should hopefully make clear whats the `Deck` object here and what's the `deck` `list`.

Comment: why would he need a getter method?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham He does not need a getter method.

Comment: why would it be even better as you suggested?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham To provide an interface for the usage of the class without having to know its internals. IMO, you should only write classes which force you to fumble around in their intestines when you are absolutely sure what you are doing. Does the OP look like such a person?

Comment: A getter method won't solve the ability to call len() on the deck issue. If he really wants to be able to call len(thedeck) on the Deck instance he needs a metaclass... see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7642535/3651800

Comment: deck = Deck.deck() resolved the issue, but now there are other issues.  

can anyone give more clarification on why it should be deck = Deck.deck() ?

Comment: After I made the change, there is now an error with the 'deal' function. 'List' object has no attribute 'deal_card'.  How can I resolve that?

Comment: @user3002315 I tried to explain it in my post, which part is unclear? In short: x = Deck() creates an object which has an instance variable deck. You can access this instance variable with the dot notation, i.e. Deck().deck or x.deck for this example. The shuffle function only works on lists. A Deck object is not a list, but its instance variable deck is. As for your new problem: you need to call deal_card on a Deck object, not on the list deck.

Comment: @user3002315 I edited my post in response to your comment.

Comment: Great so now shuffle and deal work with no errors.  Now I'm having problems with my prompt function.  I called the prompt function in the last line of my deal function.  There seems to be an error with that according to IDLE.  Also there seems to be an error with the first 2 print statements in the prompt function.  The error message says that 'player' is not defined.  but I defined player as a Hand object in the deal function.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it because I have to call player and dealer as global variables in my prompt function?

Comment: @user3002315 Please make a new question and be more specific this time. We cannot solve all your problems in the comments to my answer. It would also be nice of you to accept one of the answers in this topic if it helped you with your original problem (Deck having no length).

Answer (score 0):

```
deck = Deck() should be deck = Deck().deck
```

Trying  `random.shuffle` on `Deck()` will result in:

```
AttributeError: Deck instance has no attribute '__len__'
```

Deck has no len, where  `Deck().deck` refers to your list of `__main__.Card instance's` which has a length.

```
In [42]: d = Deck()

In [43]: d.deck.__len__() # self.deck has a __len__() as it is a list of instances
Out[43]: 52


In [44]: d = Deck()

In [45]: d.__len__()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-c2cc108c72f0> in <module>()
----> 1 d.__len__()

AttributeError: Deck instance has no attribute '__len__'
```

[random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle)
*Shuffle the sequence x in place. The optional argument random is a 0-argument function returning a random float in [0.0, 1.0); by default, this is the function random().
Note that for even rather small len(x), the total number of permutations of x is larger than the period of most random number generators; this implies that most permutations of a long sequence can never be generated.*

Notice `len(x)`.